# "Add friend" from Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a Facebook page where we list the staff of an organization. Is it possible to populate the page with the names and profile pictures from the staff's profiles and include an "add friend" button alongside their name?

I need to know if this is possible before proceeding with design and hiring a developer.

Cassidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try take a look at this page, it seems you can do it with a dialog popup
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/